# Nginx reverse proxy microcaching not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, nginx, cache

My current config is Nginx webserver as a reverse proxy with Apache at backend for dynamic pages and Apache is configured with PHP-FPM.

My dynamic pages don't change often so I am trying to use Nginx microcaching but can't seem to get working.

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: As you're an unregistered user, you can't delete your posts. Register for an account and you'll see a "delete" button on them.

Comment: Additionally, if you *really* want your post deleted: 1. Ask nicely, 2. Flag for moderator attention, 3. Explain the exact reason why you want it gone and 4. Ask nicely.